# How do you know where the standard overrided button is clicked?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have overrided standard "New" button of [Object1] with AC and LWC(LWC inside AC).

Object0 and Object1 is Master-detail relationship

In that case, the "New" button in [Object1]'s list View and [Object0]'s related List is overrided.

My use case is that in certain circumstance, the button in related list should be disabled. So I need to know where the button is clicked.

Is it possible to know, where does the user click the New button? From pList view] or [Related list]?

I have tried recorId from the event, both are [undefined].

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isURLAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) interface for this.

Just add doInit in your CMP file:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
```

---

```
onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    var id = myPageRef.state.c__id;
}
```

The `myPageRef` variable will have additionalParams as blank when clicked from a `New` button in ListView, but when clicked from a Related List it will have values such as contact name, lookup id etc.

When clicked from `New` button on `ListView`

[image]

When clicked from `New` button on `related List`:

[image]

Comment: in document it says: In the component that you want to trigger the navigation, include an instance of the lightning:navigation component.       Because it is standard button which navigate to the aura page, I'm afraid I cannot set the pageReference to determine list view or related view

Comment: You dont need to set the page reference, `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface automatically takes care of it. And the param `additionalParam` tells you if its a list view or not, I have already implemented it and it works.

Comment: onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log(myPageRef.state)
    }    In my console, I only get a Proxy() Object and it contains nothing useful.

Comment: Do a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myPageRef))` and you will get it. Even you can use myPageRef.state.additionalParams and you will get the value.

Comment: No, In my myPageRef.state, it only has inContextOfRef, and from list view and reelated view they both have this and I am not able to diff them from each other.

Comment: I'm here from the distant future, but I think it's related to this 5 year-old known issue. The additionalParams are only in the URL if the child object has multiple record types. If anyone knows a workaround, happy to hear it.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwnpAAC/pagereference-additionalparams-attribute-doesnt-contain-default-values-when-a-lightning-component-overrides-new-action